# QGIS Opacity issue with polygons and labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer with a number of polygons. I can happily adjust the opacity of the polygons using the normal slider, but when I add labels to the polygons from the Attributes table the labels do not change their opacity in sync with the polygons.

Have I missed a setting or does this need an expression/code somewhere to create the linkage?

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't miss anything. That is not a feature supported by QGIS. You need to set the labels opacity separately in the labels menu.

You can try opening a feature request, if you think this would be a useful implementation.

Right now it is only possible to receive the symbols color by expression, but not its alpha channel. Maybe it is possible using pyqgis.